# Decision Tree Node method in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I'm trying to program a node class for a Decision Tree program. I'm not sure how to make a constructor that calls itself recursively until all the leaves are reached, and what helper methods I'll need. Here's what I have so far.

```
package DecisionTree;

public class DecisionTNode {

    Instance[] a;
    double testValue;
    DTNode left, right;



    public static DTNode sortedArrayToBST(Instance[] num, int start, int end) {
      if (start > end) {
        return null; 
      }
      int mid = start + (end-start)/2;
      DTNode root = new DTNode(num.length, num);
      root.left = sortedArrayToBST(num, start, mid-1);
      root.right = sortedArrayToBST(num, mid+1, end);
      return root;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sortedArrayToBST` will create all the nodes recursively.

You don't need to have a recursive constructor, you only need a very simple one that takes `testValue`'s value as parameter and sets it.

```
private DTNode(double data)
{
  testValue = data;
}
```

And change the call to:

```
DTNode root = new DTNode(num[mid].getAttribute());
```

Well, that's assuming you want your class to pretty much the way it does now. You may instead want to have a `Instance` member and set that instead (or whatever else), but the code will look very similar.

The ideal would be to use [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), but one step at a time.

You'd call it in `DecisionTree` (which you'd presumably add a `DTNode root` member to) with something like:

```
root = sortedArrayToBST(instances, 0, instances.length);
```

---

If you *want* a recursive constructor, you'd probably want to replace your `sortedArrayToBST` function with that - they will look very similar, just remove the `DTNode root = ...` line and set the member variable's value as suggested above, and remove the `return null` if statement and instead don't make the call that would trigger that at all.

```
public DTNode(Instance[] num, int start, int end)
{
  int mid = start + (end-start)/2;

  // do what you would've done in the constructor
  testValue = num[mid].getAttribute();

  // no 'return null' if statement, instead, prevent the call from ever happening
  //   leaving 'left' / 'right' as 'null' if it doesn't
  if (start <= mid-1)
    left = new DTNode(num, start, mid-1);
  if (mid+1 <= end)
    right = new DTNode(num, mid+1, end);

  // no return statement - constructors can't return anything
}
```

You'd call the recursive constructor like:

```
root = new DTNode(instances, 0, instances.length);
```

---

Also, from the code shown, there's no need to have `Instance[] a;` as a member of `DTNode`.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I'm really struggling with this question, do you see any other helper methods I could add to my DTNode class? Also, how would I constructor for my DecisionTree class? Could I just write DTNode root = new DTNode(instances)? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the need for any helper functions for what you currently have (although it's certainly possible that you'll need some when you get further with your assignment - I can only speculate as to what you need). See edit to answer for how to call it.

Comment: I know this is a lot to ask and it's perfectly fine if you decline but is there anyway I can privately message you for further help?

Comment: I'd rather not. I may not be able to answer any given question / do so well, while there are plenty of as-capable or more capable users on [so] to answer you questions.

Comment: It's all good. I'm still a little bit confused on how to replace my sortedArrayToBST function to a recursive constructor?